# using binary operator in Python... translating if (c1 >= "\xc0" & c1 <= "\xdf")

Tags: php, python

i am converting an external [class](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8/blob/master/Encoding.php) from PHP to Python, it does some tricks like :

```
if ($c1 >= "\xc0" & $c1 <= "\xdf")
[...]
$cc1 = (chr(ord($c1) / 64) | "\xc0");
[...]
$cc2 = ($c1 & "\x3f") | "\x80";
```

where $c1,^$cc1, $cc2 are characters

and i just realized that i cannot use it as such with python, as characters are string, and not duplicately seen as "binary representation of a character" where operators & and | make sense...

please, how would you translate any of these in a Pythonic way ?

```
>>> c1 = "a"
>>> (c1 & "\x3f") | "\x80"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#202>", line 1, in <module>
    (c1 & "\x3f") | "\x80"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

EDIT: actually, it seems that this PHP class do not work, so it will not fit my needs either. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The first `&` doesn't make much sense even in the PHP code.

Comment: The very premise of the "forceUTF8" class is terrible. I hope you do not rely on it in lieu of *properly handling character encodings*. In normal operation, there is no need for such code.

Comment: actually i think that the aim is to manipulate bytes of characters with mask, so i think it make sense. My question is not "does it make sense", it is not can i do the "whole encoding fixing thing with another way", but "how would you translate a character operation such as the three examples provided to Python." I have to handle some broken encoding, so i am in an 'anormal' situation, just want to check this methodology first before relying on anything else and wanted to do it from python...

Comment: I mean the `&` in `$c1 >= "\xc0" & $c1 <= "\xdf"` is misplaced, it doesn't make any sense there. And how to express such byte manipulating code in Python is a perfectly fine question, no problems here. Just saying that you're hopefully not translating this code because you need it for handling encodings. Because that's the wrong solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve with encodings.

Comment: ok i had to fix some broken encoding like the one pointed by this library : echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÃÃ©dÃÃÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football"); => Fédération Camerounaise de Football
and wanted to check this. Yes may be the first & is tricky as i do not know PHP and how PHP will handle a bitwise (boolean & boolean) operation. BTW it can make sense and probably the same as using && in this place, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ord` function to get the value and then use actual numbers to do the masking.

```
>>> c1 = "a"
>>> (ord(c1) & 0x3f) | 0x80
161
>>> hex((ord(c1) & 0x3f) | 0x80)
'0xa1'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a primitive UTF-8 encoding function.

```
c1.encode('utf-8')
```

Note that unless you use `unicode`s natively (and why aren't you?) you'll need to decode from `'latin-1'` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
>>> c1 = 'd'
>>> # if ($c1 >= "\xc0" & $c1 <= "\xdf")
... 
>>> ord(c1) >= 0xc0 and ord(c1) <= 0xdf
False
>>> # $cc1 = (chr(ord($c1) / 64) | "\xc0");
... 
>>> chr(ord(c1) / 64 | 0xc0)
'\xc1'
>>> # $cc2 = ($c1 & "\x3f") | "\x80";
... 
>>> ord(c1) & 0x3f | 0x80
164
>>>
```